# Divide List into multiple subLists

Tags: java, list, arraylist

```
//Make an array list of custom objects

List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();

userList.add(new User("ani","bha","abcd@gg.com","Monday"));

userList.add(new User("ani2","bha2","abcd2@gg.com","Tuesday"));

userList.add(new User("ani5","bha5","abcd5@gg.com","Monday"));

userList.add(new User("ani2","bha2","abcd2@gg.com","Tuesday"));

userList.add(new User("ani5","bha5","abcd5@gg.com","Monday"));
```

I want to divide userList in to two sublists.Users that contain "Monday" into one sublist and user with "Tuesday" into another sublist.

Comment: Add your User class code

Comment: You have two identical answers, at *exactly* the same time, but one has an upvote and the other doesn't :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Collectors.groupingBy()` that groups elements of the stream according to the function passed as parameter and stores them in a `Map` where the key is the result of the function and the value the associated `List` :

```
 Map<String, List<User>> collect = userList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(User::getDay));
```

Comment: What you here mean by getDay in (User::getDay).

Comment: I refer to a `String User.getDay()` method that returns the day passed as you instantiate your User : "Monday", "Tuesday". If you don't have it, you should create it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the groupingBy collector and then just grab the map value you want.

```
Map<String, List<User>> byDay = userlist.stream().collect(
  Collectors.groupingBy(User::getDay));
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers listed are surely correct, but if you are still not familiar with stream you can get a bit confused. I'm going to write an equivalent code that does exactly the same but without using the streams. Maybe it will be clearer to you:

```
Map<String, List<User>> usersByDay = new HashMap<>();
for(User u : userList)
{
    dayusers = usersByDay.getOrDefault(u.getDay(), new ArrayList<>());
    dayusers.add(u);
    usersByDay.put(u.getDay(), dayusers);
}
```

This implementation assume that your User class is defined more or less as follow:

```
public class User
{
    private String day;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String email;

    public User(....){...}

    public String getDay(){return day;}
    ...
}
```